# Use the old Layout Inspector in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, layout-inspector

It seems like Android Studio doesn't allow more to use the legacy [Layout Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) (without live updates), but that one was extremely useful.

I get it, the new one has live updates, but the connection time to the process is slow, sometimes it even restarts the activity if you don't have the non restart activity flag enabled. And personally I rarely need the live updates, I only need to inspect whatever screen I'm seeing at the moment.

Does anybody know if is possible to use the legacy layout inspector without going to a prior version of Android Studio to current stable (Arctic Fox)?

Comment: I think you can try this plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19451-legacy-layout-inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This button should disable live updates
[image]

Comment: This works for me

Answer (score 2):

I also have issues with the new Layout Inspect for my React Native app, whether live updates are off or on. However, the new Android Studio (my Android Studio's version is  Chipmunk|2021.2.1) cannot turn off "Enable Live Layout Inspector" in the settings, Google has removed this setting. But I found that in the Keymap settings, you can set shortcut keys to Legacy Layout Inspector, and then use Legacy Layout Inspector through shortcut keys. Thank Google for not removing this feature outright.
[image]

Comment: I think it's gone now